# Push notification is not working the error in terminal while i'm testing in terminal

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

```
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', "pushNEWPEM12.pem");
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase',$passphrase);
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (empty($fp))
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'title' => 'Together',
            'body' => $offer_title,
            "content-available" => 1
         ),
        'sound' => 'default'
    );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
    if (!$result)
        return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        return 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

//error In terminal is

Mac-mini:PushNotification vol$ php simplepush.php

Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /Users/vol/Desktop/PushNotification/simplepush.php on line 21

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/vol/Desktop/PushNotification/simplepush.php on line 21

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/vol/Desktop/PushNotification/simplepush.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 0 
Vol-Mac-mini:PushNotification vol$

`I'm working with push notifications. If I use the dev certificate/provision profile and testing in terminal it shows error like this.

Comment: show your php code

Comment: For wokring it in production you have to make only two changes change url to production url and change .pem file of live credential.

Comment: @Bhavin Can you please explain your answer.

Comment: @Loki - your .pem file is for prodction or developement

Comment: one more thing production APNS , we can't check , adhoc we can check, production APNS  only works after comes on live

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  
Can we test that With testflight Build? And my php script is fine or not tell me.

Comment: php file is correct , check once your pem file is production or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I created production pem file But it's not worked Can you please share any refference to create production pem.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases you can check at your end:-

1)  Make sure that you have used the right production certificate on your server side. As we need to create two different certificates for production and sandbox. Please check you are using correct certificate on server.

2) You can check that you have used the right gateway and port number on server side. Since gateway for production and sandbox are different one. Gateway used for production is:- gateway.push.apple.com. and also you are using correct password on server for your certificate your have used on your server.

3)You can check if the notification on your device is enabled or not. You need to enable it on your iPhone as well. Make sure that is on your device.

Let me know if it works for you.